# Tail file till process exits

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, pip

Going through the answers at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/270529/monitoring-a-file-until-a-string-is-found).

I'm trying to modify this to listen for multiple strings and echo custom messages such as ; 'Your server started successfully' etc

I'm also trying to tack it to another command i.e. pip

```
wait_str() {
  local file="$1"; shift
  local search_term="Successfully installed"; shift
  local search_term2='Exception'
  local wait_time="${1:-5m}"; shift # 5 minutes as default timeout

  (timeout $wait_time tail -F -n0 "$file" &) | grep -q "$search_term" && echo 'Custom success message' && return 0 || || grep -q "$search_term2" && echo 'Custom success message' && return 0

  echo "Timeout of $wait_time reached. Unable to find '$search_term' or '$search_term2' in '$file'"
  return 1
}
```

The usage I have in mind is:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt > /var/log/pip/dump.log && wait_str /var/log/pip/dump.log
```

To clarify, I'd like to get wait_str to stop tailing when pip exits, whether successfully or not.

Comment: @PS. The `tail` command does not exit. I need to do sth like this  `tail -f /var/log/pip/stderr.log | awk '/Exception/ { system("echo worked!")}' || awk '/compiler/ { system("echo worked!")}'` to test for two strings.

Comment: You seem to assume that these commands run in parallel, but your commands show serial execution. By definition, `pip` will have finished when `wait_str` runs, because you are connecting them with `&&` which waits for `pip` and examines its exit status, then runs `wait_str` only if `pip` was successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is general answer and `tail` could be replaced by any command that result in stream of lines.

IF different string needs **different** actions then use following:

```
tail -f var/log/pip/dump.log |awk '/condition1/ {action for condition-1} /condition-2/ {action for condition-2} .....'
```

If multiple conditions need **same** action them ,separate them using OR operator :

```
tail -f var/log/pip/dump.log |awk '/condition-1/ || /condition-2/ || /condition-n/ {take this action}'
```

Based on comments : Single `awk` can do this.

```
tail -f /path/to/file |awk '/Exception/{ print "Worked"} /compiler/{ print "worked"}'
```

or

```
tail -f /path/to/file | awk '/Exception/||/compiler/{ print "worked"}'
```

OR Exit if match is found

```
tail -f logfile |awk '/Exception/||/compiler/{ print "worked";exit}'
```

Comment: Thank! Just tested this it works. I'm calling tail from a script and I need it to exit so that the execution of the script can continue.

Comment: This `( tail -f -n0 logfile.log & ) | grep -q "Server Started"` this exits the pipeline when the string is found (copied over from the superuser site). I've never used awk is there a similar option that will allow exiting once the string is found?

Comment: yes,indeed you can exit from awk once string is found. Use exit after print statement inside awk like :

`awk '/Exception/||/compiler/{ print "worked";exit}'`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: I'm using Ctrl^C to stop tail when running `tail -f logfile |awk '/Exception/||/compiler/{ print "worked";exit}'`. Tried adding a second `;exit` is there a way exit tail in the one-liner after a match?

Comment: @Jonathan ,it should exit as soon as pattern is seen. `exit` in awk will take down `tail` command as well.  Are you sure that pattern is matched ? Also, you can go down to `bash` and use `tail -f logfile |grep --line-buffered -E  'Exception|compiler' | while read ; do echo "Worked" ;exit 0 ; done`

Comment: The pattern is matched twice, I'm using sh inside a docker container, alpine 
`/ # tail -f /ns/var/log/pip/stderr.log | awk '/Failed to build uwsgi/ || /compiler/ { print "worked"}'
worked
worked
^C
/ # 
`

Comment: `bash-4.3# tail -f /ns/var/log/pip/stderr.log |grep --line-buffered -E 'Exception|compiler' | while read ; do echo "Worked" ;exit 0 ; done             
grep: unrecognized option: line-buffered`

Comment: I am not sure, but I am sure this is not related to bash or awk or grep. Problem is with docker session.